# Printing out results in a map loading contents from a xlsx file using POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

so I need to print out the product id and image url from a excel file as I need to modify another file with the contents I retrieve, however for some reason the mappings is empty, but if I print the values out directly it shows them correctly.

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    static final Map<String, String> PRODUCT_CODES_BY_IMAGES = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        File file = new File("./data/stock_met_imageurls.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row currentRow = iterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                if(cell != null && cell.getCellTypeEnum().equals(CellType.STRING)) {
                    String image_url = null;
                    String product_id = null;

                    switch(cell.getColumnIndex()) {
                        case 0:
                            image_url = cell.getStringCellValue();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            product_id = cell.getStringCellValue();
                            break;
                    }

                    if(image_url != null && product_id != null) {
                        PRODUCT_CODES_BY_IMAGES.put(product_id, image_url);
                    }

                }


            }
        }

        PRODUCT_CODES_BY_IMAGES.forEach((k, v) -> {
            System.out.println("key = " + k);
            System.out.println("val = " + v);
        });

        System.out.println("Size = " + PRODUCT_CODES_BY_IMAGES.size());
    }
}
```

if I did under the cases

`System.out.println("val = " + cell.getStringCellValue());`

it prints it out correctly but for some reason the mappings is empty?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Because your map is declared as static final. Check out https://www.baeldung.com/java-final

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with anything, static implies, there is only 1 instance of it through the whole project, final means it can't be further extended or in this case can't be re-initialized. I'm only putting values in the map, also I tried removing the final keyword but nothing changed.

Comment: Even declaring the map inside the main() does not change anything.

Comment: Can you share an example of your Excel file? Just a few lines for trying!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, I added the elements in the mappings above the wrong bracket.